# GraphQL - data cannot be non input type ... Config broken?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, prisma

I seem to be running into a little bit of an issue that I can't figure out.

I created a new type `Challenge` in my `datamodel.prisma`:

```
type Challenge {
    id: ID! @id
    createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
    updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
    completed: Boolean! @default(value: false)
    title: String!
}
```

My Mutation Resolver

```
# import * from './generated/prisma.graphql'

type Mutation {
    createChallenge(title: String!): Challenge!
}
```

The `prisma.graphql` reads this:

```
type Mutation {
  createChallenge(data: ChallengeCreateInput!): Challenge!
}

input ChallengeCreateInput {
  id: ID
  completed: Boolean
  title: String!
}
```

And I am using playground to create the DB entries (the problem persists when I create the front end logic for this):

```
mutation {
  createChallenge(title: "Test Entry") {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

And, at last, my server-side logic:

```
async createChallenge(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    console.log(args);
    const challenge = ctx.db.mutation.createChallenge(
        {
            data: {
                ...args,
            },
        },
        info
    );
    console.log(challenge);
    return challenge;
},
```

I then get the following error in playground:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable '$_v0_data' cannot be non input type 'ChallengeCreateInput!'. (line 1, column 22):\nmutation ($_v0_data: ChallengeCreateInput!) {\n                     ^",
      "locations": [],
      "path": [
        "createChallenge"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't understand where this message is coming from. The data seems to be correctly handled in my server-side logic by spreading it into `data`.

I ran into an issue yesterday where my server-side logic wouldn't update, even after updating and resetting the datamodel via `prisma reset`. I had a field on my datamodel `challenge` that I had removed, but when submitting a mutation the server still errored saying it was missing that field. Could it have anything to do with that?

It might be important to know that usually, every time you run `prisma deploy` and there is nothing to update, it tells you `nothing to update`. At the moment, each time I run `prisma deploy` the same fields are being added and removed. This should only be happening once.

How do I get this Mutation to work?

Comment: `createChallenge(data:` vs `createChallenge(title:`

Comment: On what, server-side logic? playground/frontend? Resolver? They all have some from of createChallenge(...)

Comment: if in prisma generated is `data` then use `data` as parameter (object) ... resolver ... `createChallenge( ...args.data...` ... data was `null` because `title` passed

Answer (score 0):

most probably your issue is with the ID field. You have defined id to be autogenerated in the Prisma model and even though you are giving that field in the input type. So, remove the ID field from the input and then try.

Hope this helps! Let me know!